# Does IBM Watson Language Translation has opportunity to skip word(s)?

Tags: ibm-watson

I implement IBM Watson Translator and need ability to skip word(s). Is there any opportunity to do it with IBM Watson?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Watson Language Translator service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <header creationtool="" creationtoolversion=""
    segtype="phrase" o-tmf="" adminlang="en"
    srclang="en" datatype="PlainText" o-encoding="UTF-8" />
  <body>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="en">
        <seg>international business machines</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="fr">
        <seg>International Business Machines</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

The above pair forces "international business machines" to be preserved in English during translation. This type of forced translation might be useful if you want to preserve improperly capitalized company names in informal communications.

More details on forced glossary customization are available here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/language-translator/customizing.html#forced-glossary-customization

This customization might help you skip words without translating.

Comment: Yes, I read it, but there is no exact skipping as I need. But any way thanks.

Comment: @ValeriyTarasenko Cna you give me an example of what you intend to achieve?

Comment: I would like to have somthing like this
"Phrase. Phrase. <tag>this words will stay same</tag> word word."
or 
"Phrase. Phrase. {tag}nontranslateed{/tag} word word."
And if I have many texts with different words/quotes it will be really hard to add them all to model.xml